# i have many data-self element, but how can i get all of them?

Tags: javascript, html

just like this:

```js
// with jquery i have tried

$('body').data('self'); // undefined
$('body').data('date-self'); //undefined

// but i can use this method to get the defined element

$('button').data('self'); // self

// with javascript 

document.querySelector('button').dataset.self // self
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div data-self="self">self</div>
    <span data-self="self">span self</div>
    <ul>
      <li data-self="self">li1 self</li>
      <li data-self="self">li2 self</li>
    </ul>
    <button data-self="self">button self</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

but i can't find a way to get all elements with 'data-self'.

if someone know, please tell me, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first off, your HTML is invalid. `date-self` should probably be `data-self`, yes?

Second, getting the value in `data-*` attributes is done using the `.data()` method:

```
var dataSelf = $(".elem").data("self");
```

You can also get it directly from the attribute, like so:

```
var dataSelf = $(".elem").attr("data-self");
```

Selecting elements that *have the `data-self` attribute* is done as follows:

```
var elementsWithDataSelf = $("[data-self]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just going to have to iterate over them all.

```
var $elems = $('[data-self]');
var selfs = [];
$elems.each(function ($elem) {
  selfs.push($elem.data('self'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all elements where 'data-self' attribute is set using this query:

```
var elementList=document.querySelectorAll('[data-self]');
```

If you need to select all elements where 'data-self' attribute is equal to something then you can use next line:

```
var elementList=document.querySelectorAll('[data-self="something"]');
```